# Android Zoom inside onMarkerClick Failure

Tags: android, google-maps

When I try to zoom in inside the onMarkerClick it appears to Listen to the zoom for just a splitsecond and then stop, It does animate to the right LatLng though..

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
GoogleMap mMap;
....
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if(marker.equals(myExampleMarker)) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(LatLng, zoomLevel));
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow this animates the camera to the desired LatLng that I've entered but somehow the Zoomlevel adjusts just a little bit in the right direction but stops after a split second. Is there a problem with changing zoom levels inside OnMarkerClick and if so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to make a `Handler` and a little bit `delay` for zooming.

Sample code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
GoogleMap mMap;
....
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if(marker.equals(myExampleMarker)) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(LatLng, zoomLevel));
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    }
}
```